# Datatable group and pivot

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DT with following structure

```
unit | value | date
-------------------------
 A   |   2   | 01-01-2000
 B   |   3   | 01-01-2000
 A   |   4   | 02-01-2000
```

I would like to transform it into following

```
            |   A   |  B
 ---------------------------
 01-01-2000 |   2   |  3
 02-01-2000 |   4   |
```

What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

EDIT:
I have implemented a function for pivot, which gives me the following:

```
        |  A       |  B       |  A
--------------------------------------
value   |  2       |  3       |  4
date    |01-01-2000|01-01-2000|02-01-2000
```

But in this case I am missing grouping by columns.

By 'fastest' I mean possibly shortest code to achieve this (LINQ?). Or perhaps pivot can be achieved simultaneously in the same query?

Comment: Fastest way how?  Fastest way for somebody to give you the code? Fastest way for you to implement it yourself? Fastest performance?  There are many articles on how to pivot data that you can search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("unit", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A",2, DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B",3, DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A",4, DateTime.Parse("02-01-2000")});

            string[] uniqueUnits = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("unit")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach (string unit in uniqueUnits)
            {
                dt1.Columns.Add(unit, typeof(int));
            }
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("date"));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt1.Rows.Add();
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    newRow["date"] = group.Key;
                    newRow[row.Field<string>("unit")] = row.Field<int>("value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's more lines of code but can be done with only one loop as well:

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("unit",typeof(string)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("value",typeof(int)));
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date",typeof(DateTime)));

        dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", 2, DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000") });
        dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", 3, DateTime.Parse("01-01-2000") });
        dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", 4, DateTime.Parse("02-01-2000") });

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date", typeof(DateTime)));
        dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["date"], };
        List<string> cols = new List<string>();
        List<DateTime> ds = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
        {
            string unit = dr1["unit"].ToString();
            if (!cols.Contains(unit))
            {
                dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(unit, typeof(int)));
                cols.Add(unit);
            }
            DateTime pkDate = (DateTime)dr1["date"];
            if (!ds.Contains(pkDate))
            {
                ds.Add(pkDate);
                DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
                dr["date"] = dr1["date"];
                dr[unit] = dr1["value"];
                dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                dt2.Rows.Find(pkDate)[unit] = dr1["value"];
            }
        }
```