# How can I create a "dynamic" list in C# from query with properties named like columns of a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, list

I want to try this: every time that I execute a query, I want to automatically create a list of objects, every property of the object must be called the same as the column name of table.

Something like this:

`my_Sql_table`:

| code | number | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 43 | qwe |
| 002 | 721 | plo |

My C# controller:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
cmd.CommandText = "select  * from my_Sql_table";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

sqlConn.ConnectionString = _configuration["dbConnectionString"];

using (sqlConn)
{
     sqlConn.Open();

     SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (reader.Read())
     {
         // the code here
     }
}
```

In C#, my result will be this:

```
myList:

[0] code: "001", number: "43", brand: "qwe"
[1] ....
```

Now imagine have many queries to do with a large number of columns, my goal is not to create so many models, and read properties more easily when I use javascript.

Comment: You want a pivot table like in excel.  See my code at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995409/datatable-group-and-pivot?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng but with this, i need to nominate manually every column. I would like a way that do this automatically. For example A table has 10 column, the Object will have 10 comuns with same name. if next table B has 50 columns do the same

Comment: Look at how I create the columns in the pivot table.  I use DISTINCT so I get all the values in one column of the query from database.  Then create X columns in the datatable.

Comment: This is [very easy with Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#execute-a-query-and-map-it-to-a-list-of-dynamic-objects)

Comment: So you actually want sql to json? Skipping c# entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change this according to your output format, but this is an idea of how to go about getting your result. I am using Dictionary with ExpandoObject to override the limit on variable allocations. Also try implementing a DataTable instead of reading directly from a SqlDataReader as this tends to cause problems.

```
using System.Dynamic;

    private IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> GetQueryToList()
    {
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
cmd.CommandText = "select  * from my_Sql_table";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

sqlConn.ConnectionString = _configuration["dbConnectionString"];

using (sqlConn)
{   
     var list = new List<ExpandoObject>(); 
     sqlConn.Open();

     SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (reader.Read())
     {
     var expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
     for (var i = 0; i<reader.FieldCount; i++)
     {
     ((IDictionary<string, object>) expandoObject).Add(
     reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
            }
     list.Add(expandoObject);
     }
}
```